# there is a problem in get function cant read the URL don't know why?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgRCy.png)it is a simple program to test chrome driver in selenium it run but can't get the URL

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class chromeTest:
    def testMethod2(self):
        driverLocation = "D:\\workspace_python\\chromedriver.exe"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverLocation
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
        driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com")

ff = chromeTest
ff.testMethod2(0)
```

Comment: the chrome open but doesn't get the URL

Comment: it doesn't open "http://www.letskodeit.com" the chrome program run wit data; URL

Comment: please dont use the comments sections to revise your answer. Instead, click the little edit link under your post, and then change your post. Good style is to make your edits highlighted by writing them in boldface and noting that they are edits. Also, please try to use punctuation to make your sentences more readable. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you have to use `()` to create instance od class - `ff = chromeTest()`. If you don't need instance then why you create class ?

Comment: did you try without PyCharm? Do you have problem with different URLs? Do you have `chromedriver.exe` in `D:\\workspace_python` ? Is this version for your current web browser ? Different crhomedrivers works with different Chome Web Browser.